# How to group on status and output in JSON

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rabl

I am creating a Rails 5 app.
In this app I got Candidate models. Each Candidate got a status attribute.
I want to create a JSON (Jbuilder) output that looks like below. Meaning I want to group the output on Status attribute of each Candidate.

```
[{
        "total_entries": 1
    },
    {
        "entries": [{
            "pending": [{
                "id": 4,
                "name": "James Britain"
            }],
            "completed": [{
                "id": 4,
                "name": "James Britain"
            }, {
                "id": 4,
                "name": "Anna Tompson"
            }]
        }]
    }
]
```

I tried the following but that did not work.

```
Candidate.select('status, firstname').group('status, firstname')
```

Please help!

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `group_by` and the syntax is slightly different based on your db and version of rails. Supplying those would help nail down the answer, but this is the widest usecase:

```
Candidate.select('status, firstname').group_by(&:status)
```

Comment: Worked fine! BUT one issue. It outputs an array and my Jbuilder (I was wrong I am not using Rabl) code cannot handle that. I get undefined method `id' for #<Array:0x007ffb50b2c3b8>.

Comment: would you need to add the id to the select statement? like maybe `Candidate.select('id, status, firstname').group_by(&:status)` like this?